# Why are html ids exposed as global variables in browser

Tags: javascript, html

The html ids are exposed as global variables in browser.

```
<span id="someid" class="clsname1 clsname2 clsname3"></span>
```

For the above html snippet, you can find a global variable called someid.  Among many things, you can do the following to it, say, in your console.

```
>someid.id \\gives back someid
>someid.className \\gives list of classes as string
>someid.classList \\gives an array
```

However, it did not conflict with existing global variables  such as location, navigator, etc when you create a DOM like

1) Is it okay to access them and use in your scripts?

2) Why does browsers expose them globally like this?

3) I think developers should be cautious using id names as variables in their programs as they might impact.

Comment: Why developers should be cautious? How you think it can impact in particular?

Comment: Please can you tell me what is your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Named elements are added as properties to the `window` object. This is called  [named access on the window object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object).

> What are ‘named elements’? Anything with an id, and anything with a
>   name being used for ‘identifying’ purposes: that is, forms, images,
>   anchors and a few others, but not other unrelated instances of a name
>   attribute, like control-names in form input fields, parameter names in
>   `<param>` or metadata type in `<meta>`. ‘Identifying’ names are the ones
>   that should should be avoided in favour of id.

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/4185234).